# Tag request FlexiContent

Tags: feature-request, tags

Never really made a tag suggestion but I dont have enough rep obvioulsy to make it myself. I am trying to use [FlexiContent](http://www.flexicontent.org/) as a CCK and find the [tutorials](http://www.flexicontent.org/documentation/tutorials.html) on their site lacky (Part of it is a language barrier.) Wondering if there are other here that use it. Might have a place here long term as a tag.

Comment: Have you seen questions on this site for flexicontent?

Comment: Yes.. not lots but they exist

Comment: Tag has been made and the one question that definitely fits this has been edited to have this tag too. Feel free to edit the tag page: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexicontent as well as ask questions about it and tag them with this tag!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have ever seen any questions for this. If people want to add a specific tag to a question, they can simply do so by typing it manually in the tag section when creating a new question. Only those extensions that are very popular such as K2 and Community Builder should have their own dedicate tags with descriptions. If we start creating them for less popular extensions then it should be done for all of them (theoretically).

So simply add them to your question when creating it which will store it in the tag database automatically.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. I might have questions that, if nothing else, I could answer for the good of the community.